# Does beforeEach() work as expected in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I am trying to use `beforeEach()` in my cypress test but my dev says that the cypress code gets loaded at once and before each might not functions as its meant to. Is that true ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your expectation is of `beforeEach()`. But I can tell you how it works. A `beforeEach()` is indeed loaded at once, but it is performed before each `it()` in your test. So if your goal is to have the steps in the `beforeEach` to be executed in every test, than it works exactly as you wish.